# Significato di "giocarsi la chiacchiera"

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Torno da Cortina. Una puntatina per distrarmi.» E raccontava chi c’era, le solite storie, la solita gente, i soliti napoletani che fuori **si giocano la chiacchiera**, fanno gli snob – e tutto con un’aria annoiata. Era proprio bravo, credibile, convincente, insomma pareva un milionario.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "giocarsi la chiacchiera" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho ricercato alla voce "chiacchiera" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Sapreste spiegare cosa significa?

Comment: A Roma non pervenuta. :)

Comment: @DaG: Allora forse si dovrebbe aggiungere la tag "regional".